# Adiabatic approximation with scaled time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, approximations

In this [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405059) (page 3) they have the following expression for the coefficients in the adiabatic approximation:

$$\dot a_k(t)=-a_k(t) \langle k| \dot k \rangle -\sum_{n\ne k} a_n(t) \frac{\langle k(t)|\dot H(t) |n(t)\rangle}{g_{nk}(t)} e^{-i\int^t_0 dt'g_{nk}(t')}$$
(I have made explicit time dependencies)
They then make the substitution:
$$t=sT$$
where $T$ is the time scale on which the Hamiltionian changes and get the following expression:
$$\dot a_k(s)=-a_k(s) \langle k| \dot k \rangle -\sum_{n\ne k} a_n(s) \frac{\langle k(s)|\dot H(s) |n(s)\rangle}{g_{nk}(s)} e^{-iT\int^s_0 ds'g_{nk}(s')}$$
I am fine with all of these subsititions, execpt for the cofficents $a_n(s)$ which I cannot convince myself should not also be a function of $T$ i.e. $a_n(s,T)$. Please can someone explain the reasoning of this to me?